# Hapi is automatically converting my query parameter

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm using Hapi in Node.js to create an API. However, before the request reaches my handler method for this particular GET request, Hapi has altered my query parameters. This was printed from the 'onPreHandler' server extension. Using `console.log(request)`.

```
url: 
  Url {
    search: '?number=+7025552584',
    query: { number: ' 7025552584' },
    pathname: '/api/getNumberInfo',
    path: '/api/getNumberInfo?number=+7025552584'
```

Is it possible to disable Hapi from replacing the "+" with a space?

What are some work-arounds?

- Change it to a POST request? (This works, just tested it)
- Parse `request.url.search` myself?

Thanks!

Comment: URL encode the `+` in the number so it's properly decoded: '%2B7025552584' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: You're right. Thank you @MattHarrison